# Guidelines for Spring controllers in transactional envrionment

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, model-view-controller, transactions

What is the right way to implement a restful-controller returning Json-objects with Spring MVC and JPA?

Focus:

- Where should occur the conversion from json to entities (entity loading)?
- Where should occur the conversion from entities to json?
- Where should be placed the @Transactional statements?
- Important: entities contains lazy loaded collection!

A first naive design was:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonUser doSomethingOnUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {

    // 1. load entities by ids
    User user = mUserRepository.findOne(userId);

    // 2. eventually validate

    // 3. perform changes on entities (create, update, delete)
    mUserService.DoSomething(user);

    // 4. convert back to json
    return mUserPresenter.convertToJsonUser(user);
}
```

Motivation was to:

- perform the conversion from `id` to `entity` as soon as possible
- let the controller remain responsible for the presentation, in this case convert from entities to json

But I get several issues with transactions boundaries combined with lazy-loading and entities relations, so that it seems to be a bad design.

What are your best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try structuring it like this, this is a very frequent solution, it's the Domain Driven Development approach described in the [blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), here is a [free short version](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) approved by the same author:

### Controller

The controller is not transactional and does not have business logic, so it does not try to navigate the user object graph which could cause `LazyInitializationExceptions`.

If by any reason other than business logic this is needed, then either the controller calls a service that returns an eager fetched object graph or it first merges the object into a session.

This is meant to be the exception and not the rule, in general the role of the controller is to validate the input parameters to see if they have the correct type/mandatory parameters, call the business logic and prepare a DTO for the response if one is needed.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonUser doSomethingOnUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {

    // all the business logic is in the service layer
    User user = mUserService.doSomething(userId);

    // conversion to DTO is handled in the controller layer, 
    // the domain does not know about DTOs
    return mUserPresenter.convertToJsonUser(user);
}
```

### Service

The service contains the business logic written using the domain model, and defines the transaction scope.

```
@Service
public class MyUserService {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public User doSomething(String userId) {

       //this object is attached due to @Transactional, no exceptions will be thrown
       User user = mUserRepository.findOne(userId);

       // do something with the attached object
       ....
}
```

### Repository

The repository is usually not transactional, as it cannot know the scope of the transaction it's in. It is responsible for retrieving data from the database and transforming it in domain objects, and for storing domain objects in the database:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void someDataRelatedMethod(...) {
        ... use entity manager ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Again, I understand, that it is a "frequent design". Everybody tells it. But I wish to have a real argumentation why this design is better than any other. And precisely, the lazy-loading issues occuring with this design, let me think it is not adequate! Why don't keep the transaction open until the transformation to DTO??? So why don't set the controller operation transactional?

Comment: I do the same but services should definitely know about DTOs. If this is SPA application then DTOs is actually domain model for this application. Entities are just.. entities: POJOs to make ORM work. Controller work is to translate these DTOs to JSON and back (usually is done automatically by Jackson), validate user input, but not to convert Entities to DTOs and back. With this design there are no Lazy exceptions and controllers is lean and simple.

Comment: Dtos are ui specific, if the service layer returns dtos then its only used by the view. If a web service tries to reuse the same service layer it will have to map dtos to some other dtos specific of the service. Maybe jaxb pojos. There are other ways to aviud lazy init exceptions, like open session in view or biilduing eager queries. In the end we need to query the exact data we need the orm cannot do it optimally for us